# Blank Print Preview Window in Microsoft Edge

Tags: jsp, pdf, microsoft-edge, print-preview

When the `content-type` header from the server is `application/pdf` I'm getting a blank *Print Preview* window in Microsoft Edge. See

[Linked Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrvos.png)

In other browsers the *Print Preview* window works as expected.

Are any extra headers for Edge, in order to resolve this? If not, what is likely to be the solution?

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge are you using, and is this PDF publicly accessible? I am an engineer on the Edge team, and have received one other report of this issue from another user. I'd love to look into it further.

Comment: @Sampson I'm using Microsoft 25.10586.0.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 13.10586 version of edge . Pdf is not publicly accessible and more over it is dynamically generated from backend

Comment: How are you generating the PDF, and what other headers are you sending?

Comment: Content-Disposition: inline; filename*=UTF-8''abc.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf
 
 for Edge browser i tried with or without  additional header  "X-UA-Compatible : IE=edge" but did not worked out.

Comment: What server-side library do you use to generate the PDF? Please provide as much detail as you possibly can; I'd like to setup a similar environment on my end for further testing. If you could stand up an identical environment that I could access, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm using com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar for generating the pdf .My observation was that getting blank print preview in edge browser when i rendered pdf on html elements like object , emded ,iframe ,form  coming from backend with headers Content-Type:application/pdf and Content-Disposition:inline; .please find my sample code(written in java) in this https://github.com/SravanChithari13/PdfPoc . Please run this code and open in edge .after rendering pdf on page use browser print option so that you get to know the problem

Comment: is there no one to help me out this issue ?

Comment: Can you stand up a URL that I can access to repro the issue?

Comment: i provide sample code here https://github.com/SravanChithari13/PdfPoc with which you can reproduce  issue . local url is http://localhost:8080/PdfPoc/pdfPrint

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a fix, but we are experiencing this issue as well. PDFs are generated with MigraDoc and PdfSharp, but they print blank on Edge and only on Edge.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929282/edge-browser-appears-to-discard-response-payload